# Django doesn't use atomic transactions by default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, transactions, race-condition

I read the django documentation about [Database transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/#module-django.db.transaction).

Then, [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/#django-s-default-transaction-behavior) says:

> Django’s default behavior is to run in autocommit mode. Each query is
> immediately committed to the database, unless a transaction is active.

So, as the section says, **Django doesn't use atomic transactions by default?**

Comment: Yes, Django doesn't use atomic transactions by default.

Comment: Also how would having atomic transactions for the database change anything? I assume you mean the user spends time filling the form meanwhile someone else has already updated the model instance. That isn't something database transactions would help with (In fact it would be a very messy feature to implement such locking)

Answer (score 3):

Django doesn't use **Atomic Transaction** by default for **Django views** while Django uses **Atomic Transaction** by default for **Django admin**.

Using **PostgreSQL**, I experimented if **Atomic Transaction** is used for **Django views** by default or not with the code below. **"SELECT", "INSERT", "UPDATE" and "DELETE" queries** are run by **"Animal" class code** in **"test()" view** on **"views.py"** as shown below. *You can also see [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73349428/by-default-is-transaction-atomic-already-used-for-the-data-which-is-added-and/73601492#73601492) which experimented if **Atomic Transaction** is used for **Django admin** by default or not:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Animal

def test(request):

    animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
    print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

    Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

    Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

    Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" 

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

And, this is **"urls.py"** below:

```py
# "store/urls.py"

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "store"

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', views.test, name="test"),
]
```

Then, I open **the url "http://localhost:8000/store/test/"** to run **"test" view** as shown below:

[image]

Now, between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries**, **only "DELETE" query** is run by **"Animal" class code** in **"test()"** view., So, **Atomic Transaction** is not used for **Views** by default. *These logs below are **the query logs of PostgreSQL**. You can check [**On PostgreSQL, how to log SQL queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

Next, for **"test()" view**, I put **"@transaction.atomic" decorator** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Animal

@transaction.atomic # Here
def test(request):
    
    animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
    print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

    Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

    Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

    Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" 

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Or, for **"test()" view**, I put **"with transaction.atomic():"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Animal

def test(request):

    with transaction.atomic(): # Here
    
        animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
        print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

        Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" 

        return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Or, for **"test()" view**, I put **'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True** to **my PostgreSQL settings** in **"settings.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, # Here
    }
}
```

Then, I open **the url "http://localhost:8000/store/test/"** to run **"test" view** as shown below:

[image]

Now, between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries**, **"SELECT", "INSERT", "UPDATE" and "DELETE" queries** are run by **"Animal" class code** in **"test()" view**. So now, **Atomic Transaction** works:

[image]

Next, for **"test()" view**, I put both **"@transaction.atomic" decorator** and **"with transaction.atomic():"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Animal

@transaction.atomic # Here
def test(request):
    
    with transaction.atomic(): # Here
        
        animal = Animal.objects.all() # For "SELECT" query
        print(animal) # Needed to run "SELECT" query

        Animal(name='Dog').save() # For "INSERT" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Dog").update(name="Cat") # For "UPDATE" query

        Animal.objects.filter(name="Cat").delete() # For "DELETE" 

        return HttpResponse("Test")
```

And, I also put **'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True** to **my PostgreSQL settings** in **"settings.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, # Here
    }
}
```

Then, I open **the url "http://localhost:8000/store/test/"** to run **"test" view** as shown below:

[image]

Now, between **"BEGIN" and "COMMIT" queries**, **2 "SAVEPOINT" and 2 "RELEASE SAVEPOINT" queries** are run as shown below:

[image]