# By default, is transaction already used for Django Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, transactions, atomic

I checked **Django repository** on GitHub. Then, [transaction.atomic(using=using, savepoint=False)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/base.py#L875) and [transaction.mark_for_rollback_on_error(using=using)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/base.py#L877) are called in [save_base()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/base.py#L840) which is called in [save()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/base.py#L776) in [class Model(metaclass=ModelBase):](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/base.py#L477) as shown below:

```py
# "django/django/db/models/base.py"

class Model(metaclass=ModelBase):
    # ...
    def save(
        self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None
    ):
        # ...
        self.save_base(
            using=using,
            force_insert=force_insert,
            force_update=force_update,
            update_fields=update_fields,
        )
    # ...    
    def save_base(
        self,
        raw=False,
        force_insert=False,
        force_update=False,
        using=None,
        update_fields=None,
    ):
        # ...  
        # A transaction isn't needed if one query is issued.
        if meta.parents:
            context_manager = transaction.atomic(using=using, savepoint=False) # Here
        else:
            context_manager = transaction.mark_for_rollback_on_error(using=using) # Here
        with context_manager:
            # ...
```

So, by default, **transaction** is already used for **Django Admin**, right?

So, in `class Person(models.Model):`, if we override `save()` which calls super().save(*args, **kwargs)` in it as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # Here
```

We don't need to put `@transaction.atomic` on `save()` as shown below, right?:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    @transaction.atomic # Don't need
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or, we don't need to use `with transaction.atomic():` in `save()` as shown below, right?:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic(): # Don't need
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or, we don't need to set `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True` to **database settings** in `settings.py` as shown below, right?:

```py
# "settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, # Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you don't have to call `transaction.atomic()` if you're calling `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

Except **Djang Admin Actions**, by default **transaction** is always used for **Django Admin** whether or not `save()` is overridden, overridden `save()` has `super().save()` and overridden `save()` has `@transaction.non_atomic_requests` or not. So, we don't need `@transaction.atomic` or `with transaction.atomic():` for overridden `save()` and don't need to set `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True` to **database settings** in `settings.py`. *[My post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74728248/how-to-disable-transaction-in-django-admin) explains how to disable **transaction** for **Django Admin** and [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965894/by-default-is-transaction-used-in-django-admin-actions) explains about **Django Admin Actions with non-transaction by default**.

I experimented if by default, **transaction** is always used for **Django Admin**. I used **PostgreSQL**. *You can also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71628619/django-doesnt-use-atomic-transactions-by-default/73605627#73605627) which experiments if **Atomic Transaction** is used for **Django View** by default or not:

For unoverridden `save()` as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Here
    #     super().save(*args, **kwargs) # Here
```

Or for overridden `save()` with `super().save()` and `@transaction.non_atomic_requests` as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    @transaction.non_atomic_requests # Here
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Here
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # Here
```

I add **John**:

[image]

Then, two `INSERT` queries are run between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` queries as shown below. *These logs below are **the query logs of PostgreSQL** and you can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries#answer-75031321) explaining how to enable and disable query logs on PostgreSQL:

[image]

Next, update **`John`** to **`Tom`**:

[image]

Then, one `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, and `INSERT` queries are run between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` queries as shown below:

[image]

Next, delete **Tom**:

[image]

Then, one `SELECT`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` queries are run between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` queries as shown below:

[image]

Next, for overridden `save()` without `super().save()` but with `@transaction.non_atomic_requests`:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    @transaction.non_atomic_requests # Here
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Here
        pass
        # super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I add **John**. *Actually, **John** is not added because overridden `save()` doesn't have `super().save()`:

[image]

Then, one `INSERT` query is run between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` queries as shown below:

[image]

So as the experiments above, we can see that by default, **transaction** is always used for **Django Admin** whether or not `save()` is overridden, overridden `save()` has `super().save()` and overridden `save()` has `@transaction.non_atomic_requests`. So again, we don't need to use `@transaction.atomic` or `with transaction.atomic():` for overridden `save()`.

In addition, for overridden `save()` with `super().save()` and `@transaction.atomic` as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    @transaction.atomic # Here
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Here
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # Here
```

Or, for overridden `save()` with `super().save()` and `with transaction.atomic():` as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Here
        
        with transaction.atomic(): # Here
            super().save(*args, **kwargs) # Here
```

I add **John**:

[image]

Then, one `SAVEPOINT` and `RELEASE SAVEPOINT` and two `INSERT` queries are run between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` queries as shown below:

[image]

Next, for overridden `save()` with `super().save()` as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Here
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # Here
```

I set `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True` to **PostgreSQL settings** in `settings.py`:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, # Here
    }
}
```

Then, I add **John** as shown below:

[image]

Then, two `SELECT` and `INSERT` and one `SAVEPOINT` and `RELEASE SAVEPOINT` are run between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` queries as shown below:

[image]

Next, for overridden `save()`, I put both `@transaction.atomic` and `with transaction.atomic():` as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    @transaction.atomic # Here
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Here
        
        with transaction.atomic(): # Here
            super().save(*args, **kwargs) # Here
```

And, I also set `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True` to **PostgreSQL settings** in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, # Here
    }
}
```

Then, I add **John** as shown below:

[image]

Then, two `SELECT` and `INSERT` and three `SAVEPOINT` and `RELEASE SAVEPOINT` are run between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` queries as shown below:

[image]