# By default, is transaction used in Django Admin Actions?

Tags: python, django, transactions, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I know that by default, transaction is used in **Django Admin** when adding, changing and deleting data according to my tests.

But, I selected **Delete selected persons** and clicked on **Go** in **Django Admin Actions**. *I use PostgreSQL:

[image]

Then, clicked on **Yes, I'm sure** to delete data:

[image]

Now, **only one query `DELETE`** is run without including one or more other queries between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` as shown below so I doubt that by default, transaction is used in **Django Admin Actions**. *These below are **the PostgreSQL query logs** and you can check [**how to log PostgreSQL queries**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601) :

[image]

So by default, is transaction used in **Django Admin Actions**?

Answer (score 2):

No, by default, transaction is not used in **Django Admin Actions**.

First, you can see `@transaction.atomic` or `with transaction.atomic():` is not used for **the default [delete_queryset()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1234)** below:

```py
class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    
    # ...

    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        """Given a queryset, delete it from the database."""
        queryset.delete()

    # ...
```

Second, if you add **[select_for_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) code** to `delete_queryset()` by overriding it as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        print(queryset.select_for_update()) # Here
        queryset.delete()
```

Then, select **Delete selected persons** and click on **Go** in **Django Admin Actions**:

[image]

Then, click on **Yes, I'm sure** to delete data:

[image]

You will get the error below because `select_for_update()` needs to be used with **transaction** so which means *by default, transaction is not used in **Django Admin Actions***:

> django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: select_for_update cannot be used outside of a transaction.