# How to remove a useless "UPDATE" query when overriding "response_change()" in Django Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sql-update, django-admin

In `FruitAdmin():`, I overrode [**response_change()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_change) with the code to capitalize the name which a user inputs on **Change fruit** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Fruit

@admin.register(Fruit)
class FruitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_change(self, request, obj): # Here
        obj.name = obj.name.upper()
        obj.save()
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

Then, I input `orange` to **Name:** on **Change fruit** as shown below:

[image]

Then, the name was successfully changed from `APPLE` to `ORANGE` capitalized as shown below:

[image]

But according to PostgreSQL logs, there is **a useless `UPDATE` query** as shown below. *I use **PostgreSQL** and you can check [**On PostgreSQL, how to log queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

So, how can I remove **the useless `UPDATE` query** as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

In `FruitAdmin():`, you also need to override [**save_model()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) like below so that `obj.save()` works only when adding data on **Add fruit**. *`obj.save()` is really important:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Fruit

@admin.register(Fruit)
class FruitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        obj.name = obj.name.upper()
        obj.save()
        return super().response_change(request, obj)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): # Here
        last_part_of_path = request.path.split('/')[-2]

        if last_part_of_path == "add":
            obj.save() # Here
```

Then, if you input `orange` to **Name:** on **Change fruit** as shown below:

[image]

Then, the name is successfully changed from `APPLE` to `ORANGE` capitalized as shown below:

[image]

Then, **the useless `UPDATE` query** is removed as shown below:

[image]

Be careful, if you override `save_model()` with `pass` as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Fruit

@admin.register(Fruit)
class FruitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        obj.name = obj.name.upper()
        obj.save()
        return super().response_change(request, obj)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): # Here
        pass # Here
```

You cannot add data on **Add fruit** while you can change data on **Change fruit**:

[image]

But, if you really want to override `save_model()` with `pass` and want to add and change data, you also need to override [**response_add()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add) with `obj.save()` as shown below. *Again `obj.save()` is really important:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Fruit

@admin.register(Fruit)
class FruitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        obj.name = obj.name.upper()
        obj.save()
        return super().response_change(request, obj)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        pass

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None): # Here
        obj.save() # Here
        return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)
```

Then, you can add data on **Add fruit** as show below:

[image]

In addition, if you also want to capitalize the name which a user inputs on **Add fruit** as shown below:

[image]

You need to add `obj.name = obj.name.upper()` to `response_add()` as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Fruit

@admin.register(Fruit)
class FruitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        obj.name = obj.name.upper()
        obj.save()
        return super().response_change(request, obj)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        pass

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None): # Here
        obj.name = obj.name.upper() # Here
        obj.save()
        return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)
```

Or, you only need to override `save_model()` like below without `response_change()` and `response_add()`:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Fruit

@admin.register(Fruit)
class FruitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): # Here
        obj.name = obj.name.upper()
        obj.save()
```

Then, you can capitalize the name which a user inputs on **Add fruit**  as show below:

[image]