# How to run "AND" operator with "filter()" without "SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated:" error in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-filter, sql

I have **`Blog` model** below. *I use **Django 3.2.16** and **PostgreSQL**:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post
```

Then, **`store_blog` table** has **2 rows** below:

#### `store_blog` table:

| id | post |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **Python is popular and simple.** |
| **2** | **Java is popular and complex.** |

Then, when writing **the [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) code** with **2 `post__contains` arguments** in **`test()` view** to run **`AND` operator** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Blog
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(
             post__contains="popular", post__contains="simple"
         )      # ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑        # ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑
    print(qs)

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

I got the error below:

> SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: post__contains

So, how to run **`AND` operator** with **`filter()`** without **`SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated:` error** in Django?

Comment: Its best to post the full traceback message. Its easier to find where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You can run **`AND` operator** with **`filter()`** using **`&`** or using [**Q()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) and **`&`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Blog
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):

    # With "&"
                                                     # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="popular") & \
         Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="simple")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "&" 
                           # ↓ Here                    # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(post__contains="popular") & 
                             Q(post__contains="simple"))
    print(qs)              # ↑ Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, you can get the result below:

```
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>]> # With "&"
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>]> # With "Q()" and "&"
[22/Dec/2022 12:08:22] "GET /store/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```

And, there are **`AND` operators** according to **the query logs of PostgreSQL** as shown below and you can check [**On PostgreSQL, how to log queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601)

[image]

In addition, you can run **`OR` operator** with **`filter()`** using **`|`** or using [**Q()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) and **`|`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Blog
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):

    # With "&"
                                                     # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="popular") | \
         Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="simple")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "&" 
                           # ↓ Here                    # ↓ Here     
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(post__contains="popular") | 
                             Q(post__contains="simple"))
    print(qs)              # ↑ Here
                       
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, you can get the result below:

```
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>, <Blog: Java is popular and complex.>]>
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>, <Blog: Java is popular and complex.>]>
[22/Dec/2022 12:56:41] "GET /store/call_test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```

And, there are **`OR` operators** according to **the query logs of PostgreSQL** as shown below:

[image]

*Be careful, you shouldn't use **`and`** or **`or`** to run **`AND` or `OR` operator** because they don't work correctly according to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74885462/and-vs-and-and-or-for-and-and-or-operators-in-django/74885618#74885618) and actually, there are only examples of [**&**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#operators-that-return-new-querysets) and [**|**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#or) in the Django documentation so you should always use **`&`** and **`|`** as I showed above.