# "&" and "|" vs "and" and "or" for "AND" and "OR" operators in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sql

I have **`Blog` model** below. *I use **Django 3.2.16** and **PostgreSQL**:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post
```

Then, **`store_blog` table** has **2 rows** below:

#### `store_blog` table:

| id | post |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **Python is popular and simple.** |
| **2** | **Java is popular and complex.** |

Then, when running **the [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) code** using **`&`** or [**Q()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) and **`&`** or using **`and`** or **`Q()`** and **`and`** in **`test()` view** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Blog
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):

    # With "&"
                                                     # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="popular") & \
         Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="simple")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "&"
                           # ↓ Here                    # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(post__contains="popular") & 
            　　　　　　　　　　Q(post__contains="simple"))
    print(qs)              # ↑ Here

    # With "and"
                                                      # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="popular") and \
         Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="simple")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "and"
                           # ↓ Here                     # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(post__contains="popular") and 
            　　　　　　　　　　Q(post__contains="simple"))
    print(qs)              # ↑ Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

I got the same result below:

```
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>]> # With "&"
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>]> # With "Q()" and "&"
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>]> # With "and"
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>]> # With "Q()" and "and"
[22/Dec/2022 16:04:45] "GET /store/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```

And, when running **the `filter()` code** using **`|`** or **`Q()`** and **`|`** or using **`or`** or **`Q()`** and **`or`** in **`test()` view** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Blog
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):

    # With "|"
                                                     # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="popular") | \
         Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="simple")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "|"
                           # ↓ Here                    # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(post__contains="popular") | 
                             Q(post__contains="simple"))
    print(qs)              # ↑ Here

    # With "or"
                                                     # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="popular") or \
         Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="simple")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "or"
                           # ↓ Here                    # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(post__contains="popular") or 
                             Q(post__contains="simple"))
    print(qs)              # ↑ Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

I got the same result below:

```
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>, <Blog: Java is popular and complex.>]> # With "|"
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>, <Blog: Java is popular and complex.>]> # With "Q()" and "|"
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>, <Blog: Java is popular and complex.>]> # With "or"
<QuerySet [<Blog: Python is popular and simple.>, <Blog: Java is popular and complex.>]> # With "Q()" and "or"
[22/Dec/2022 16:20:27] "GET /store/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```

So, are there any differences between **`&`** and **`and`** and **`|`** and **`or`** for **`AND` and `OR` operators** in Django?

Answer (score 2):

Your test data is quite insufficient for this test since both rows contain `popular`. (IOW, anything that would find `popular` is equivalent to  `Blog.objects.all()`.)

Anyway, boolean `or` and `and` don't work correctly here (since they're just doing boolean evaluation), but you're just not noticing because of the above.
You **need** to [use the "bitwise" `|` / `&` / `^` operators, as documented.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) ("bitwise" in quotes, since the `Q` class overloads the operators to not be bitwise at all.)

For proof, let's look at the `Q`s in isolation, without querying anything...

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> pop = Q(post__contains="popular")
<Q: (AND: ('post__contains', 'popular'))>
>>> sim = Q(post__contains="simple")
<Q: (AND: ('post__contains', 'simple'))>
>>> pop and sim
<Q: (AND: ('post__contains', 'simple'))>
# ^ incorrect; evaluates to `sim`
>>> pop & sim
<Q: (AND: ('post__contains', 'popular'), ('post__contains', 'simple'))>
# ^ correct: combines the two q:s with `and`
>>> pop or sim
<Q: (AND: ('post__contains', 'popular'))>
# ^ incorrect; evaluates to `pop`
>>> pop | sim
<Q: (OR: ('post__contains', 'popular'), ('post__contains', 'simple'))>
# ^ correct: combines the two q:s with `or`
```

Answer (score 0):

When running **the `filter()` code** using **`&`** or **`Q()`** and **`&`** or using **`and`** or **`Q()`** and **`and`** in **`test()` view** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Blog
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):

    # With "&"
                                                     # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="popular") & \
         Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="simple")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "&"
                           # ↓ Here                    # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(post__contains="popular") & 
            　　　　　　　　　　Q(post__contains="simple"))
    print(qs)              # ↑ Here

    # With "and"
                                                      # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="popular") and \
         Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="simple")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "and"
                           # ↓ Here                     # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(post__contains="popular") and 
            　　　　　　　　　　Q(post__contains="simple"))
    print(qs)              # ↑ Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

**`&`** or **`Q()`** and **`&`** can run **`AND` operators** according to **the query logs of PostgreSQL** as shown below. *You can check [**on PostgreSQL, how to log queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

And, when running **the `filter()` code** using **`|`** or **`Q()`** and **`|`** or using **`or`** or **`Q()`** and **`or`** in **`test()` view** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Blog
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):

    # With "|"
                                                     # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="popular") | \
         Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="simple")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "|"
                           # ↓ Here                    # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(post__contains="popular") | 
                             Q(post__contains="simple"))
    print(qs)              # ↑ Here

    # With "or"
                                                     # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="popular") or \
         Blog.objects.filter(post__contains="simple")
    print(qs)

    # With "Q()" and "or"
                           # ↓ Here                    # ↓ Here
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(post__contains="popular") or 
                             Q(post__contains="simple"))
    print(qs)              # ↑ Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

**`|`** or **`Q()`** and **`|`** can run **`OR` operators** according to **the query logs of PostgreSQL** as shown below:

[image]