# Is there "non-lazy mode" or "strict mode" for "querysets" in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-queryset, lazy-evaluation

When I use [**select_for_update()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) and [**update()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) of [**a queryset**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) together as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
                        # Here                           # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1).update(name="Tom"))
                                                  
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Only **`UPDATE` query** is run without **`SELECT FOR UPDATE` query** as shown below. *I use **PostgreSQL** and these logs below are **the queries of PostgreSQL** and you can check [**on PostgreSQL, how to log queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

But, when I use `select_for_update()` and `update()` of **a queryset** separately then put `print(qs)` between them as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):

    qs = Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1)
    print(qs) # Here
    qs.update(name="Tom")
                                                  
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

**`SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `UPDATE` queries** are run as shown below:

[image]

Actually, this example above occurs because **QuerySets are lazy** according to [**the Django documentation**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) below:

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve
> any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long,
> and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is
> evaluated.

But, this is not simple for me. I just want **normal database behavior**.

Now, is there **non-lazy mode** or **strict mode** for **querysets** in Django?

Answer (score 0):

> But, this is not simple for me. I just want normal database behavior.

Non-lazy querysets would not be easy either. Imagine a `QuerySet` that looks like:

```
Person.objects.all().filter(id=1)
```

If the queryset was *eager* it would fetch first *all* `Person`s, because of the `Person.objects.all()`, and then fetch the filtered ones, and perhaps update the records, even if fetching the items was not necessary at all. If the number of `Person`s is huge, it could even take that much memory that the server crashes.

You can force evaluation for example with `bool(…)`, `len(…)`, `list(…)`, so:

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Person


@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    qs = Person.objects.filter(id=1).select_for_update()
    bool(qs)  # noqa: evaluate the queryset
    qs.update(name='Tom')       
    return HttpResponse('Test')
```