# What is "django_admin_log" used for in Django Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, logging, django-admin

When adding data (I use PostgreSQL):

[image]

**"django_admin_log"** is inserted as shown below. *These below are **the PostgreSQL query logs** and you can check [**how to log PostgreSQL queries**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

And, when changing data:

[image]

**"django_admin_log"** is inserted as shown below:

[image]

And, when clicking **Delete** on **`Change` page**:

[image]

Then, clicking **Yes, I'm sure** to delete data:

[image]

**"django_admin_log"** is inserted as shown below:

[image]

So, what is **"django_admin_log"** used for in Django Admin?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's used for the LogEntry feature of django that lets you track everything that is happening throught the admin panel.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#logentry-objects