# How to retry when exception occurs in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, exception, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I want to retry if exception occurs in **Django Admin**:

1. When trying to add data:

[image]

2. When trying to change data:

[image]

3. When clicking on **Delete** on **"Change" page**:

[image]

Then clicking on **Yes, I'm sure** to try deleting data:

[image]

4. When clicking on **Go** on **"Select to change" page**:

[image]

Then clicking on **Yes, I'm sure** to try deleting data:

[image]

I have **`Person` model** below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And, **`Person` admin** below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

So, how can I retry when exception occurs in **Django Admin**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `retry()` below to retry **Django Admin** 0 or more times with 0 or more interval seconds:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.db import DatabaseError, OperationalError, transaction, router
from django.contrib import messages, admin
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from time import sleep
from .models import Person
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
csrf_protect_m = method_decorator(csrf_protect)

def retry(count, interval=1):
    def _retry(func):
        def core(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal count
            if callable(count):
                count = 2
            for i in range(count+1):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except DatabaseError as e:
                    print(e)
                    if i == count:
                        messages.error(args[1], "Error occurred, try again!")
                        return redirect("/".join(args[1].path.split('/')[0:4]))
                    sleep(interval)
        return core
    
    if callable(count):
        return _retry(count)
    return _retry

# ...
```

Then, using `@retry(4, 2)` for **the overridden [changeform_view()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1743)** can retry adding and changing data 4 times with 2 interval seconds in addition to a normal try each time exception occurs as shown below. *`@retry(4, 2)` must be **the 1st decorator from the top** to work properly if there are multiple decorators:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.db import DatabaseError, OperationalError, transaction, router
from django.contrib import messages, admin
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from time import sleep
from .models import Person
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
csrf_protect_m = method_decorator(csrf_protect)

def retry(count, interval=1):
    # ...

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @retry(4, 2) # Must be the 1st decorator to work properly
    @csrf_protect_m
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url="", extra_context=None):
        with transaction.atomic(using=router.db_for_write(self.model)):
            return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

So, let's raise **[OperationalError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/exceptions/#django.db.OperationalError) exception** in **the overridden [response_add()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add) and [response_change()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_change)** as shown below:

```py
# ...

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @retry(4, 2) # Must be the 1st decorator to work properly
    @csrf_protect_m
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url="", extra_context=None):
        with transaction.atomic(using=router.db_for_write(self.model)):
            return super()._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        raise OperationalError("Exception occurs") # Here
        return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        raise OperationalError("Exception occurs") # Here
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

Now, if trying to add data:

[image]

Adding data is retried 4 times in addition to a normal try as shown below:

```
Exception occurs # Normal try
Exception occurs # 1st retry
Exception occurs # 2st retry
Exception occurs # 3rd retry
Exception occurs # 4th retry
[30/Dec/2022 22:01:41] "POST /admin/store/person/add/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[30/Dec/2022 22:01:41] "GET /admin/store/person HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Dec/2022 22:01:41] "GET /admin/store/person/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21364
[30/Dec/2022 22:01:41] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3195
```

And, transaction is run 5 times (The light blue one is a normal try and the yellow ones are 4 retries) according to **the PostgreSQL query logs** below. *You can check [**how to log PostgreSQL queries**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

Then finally, the page is redirected to **"Select to change" page** without adding data as shown below:

[image]

Next, if trying to change data from `John` to `David`:

[image]

Changing data is retried 4 times in addition to a normal try as shown below:

```
Exception occurs # Normal try
Exception occurs # 1st retry
Exception occurs # 2st retry
Exception occurs # 3rd retry
Exception occurs # 4th retry
[30/Dec/2022 23:02:49] "POST /admin/store/person/678/change/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[30/Dec/2022 23:02:49] "GET /admin/store/person HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Dec/2022 23:02:50] "GET /admin/store/person/ HTTP/1.1" 200 22512
[30/Dec/2022 23:02:50] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3195
```

And, transaction is run 5 times (The light blue one is a normal try and the yellow ones are 4 retries) according to **the PostgreSQL query logs** below:

[image]

Then finally, the page is redirected to **"Select to change" page** without changing data as shown below:

[image]

Next, using `@retry` for **the overridden [delete_view()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_view)** can retry deleting data 2 times with 1 interval second by default in addition to a normal try each time exception occurs as shown below. *`@retry` must be **the 1st decorator from the top** if there are multiple decorators:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.db import DatabaseError, OperationalError, transaction, router
from django.contrib import messages, admin
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from time import sleep
from .models import Person
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
csrf_protect_m = method_decorator(csrf_protect)

def retry(count, interval=1):
    # ...

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @retry # Must be the 1st decorator to work properly
    @csrf_protect_m
    def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        with transaction.atomic(using=router.db_for_write(self.model)):
            return self._delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
```

So, let's raise **`OperationalError` exception** in **the overridden [response_delete()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_delete)** as shown below:

```py
# ...

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @retry # Must be the 1st decorator to work properly
    @csrf_protect_m
    def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        with transaction.atomic(using=router.db_for_write(self.model)):
            return super()._delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)

    def response_delete(self, request, obj_display, obj_id):
        raise OperationalError("Exception occurs") # Here
        return super().response_delete(request, obj_display, obj_id)
```

Now, if clicking on **Delete** on **"Change" page**:

[image]

Then clicking on **Yes, I'm sure** to try deleting data:

[image]

Deleting data is retried 2 times in addition to a normal try as shown below:

```
Exception occurs # Normal try
Exception occurs # 1st retry
Exception occurs # 2st retry
[30/Dec/2022 23:30:30] "POST /admin/store/person/680/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[30/Dec/2022 23:30:30] "GET /admin/store/person HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Dec/2022 23:30:30] "GET /admin/store/person/ HTTP/1.1" 200 22513
[30/Dec/2022 23:30:31] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3195
```

And, transaction is run 3 times (The light blue one is a normal try and the yellow ones are 2 retries) according to **the PostgreSQL query logs** below:

[image]

Then finally, the page is redirected to **"Select to change" page** without deleting data as shown below:

[image]

Finally, using `@retry` for **the overridden [delete_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_queryset)** can retry deleting data 2 times with 1 interval second by default in addition to a normal try each time exception occurs as shown below. *By default, **transaction** is not used for **Django Admin Actions** and `@retry` must be **the 1st decorator from the top** to work properly if there are multiple decorators:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.db import DatabaseError, OperationalError, transaction, router
from django.contrib import messages, admin
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from time import sleep
from .models import Person
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
csrf_protect_m = method_decorator(csrf_protect)

def retry(count, interval=1):
    # ...

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @retry # Must be the 1st decorator to work properly
    @transaction.atomic
    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.delete()
```

So, let's raise **`OperationalError` exception** in **the overridden `delete_queryset()`** as shown below:

```py
# ...

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @retry # Must be the 1st decorator to work properly
    @transaction.atomic
    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.delete()
        raise OperationalError("Exception occurs") # Here
```

Now, if clicking on **Go** on **"Change" page** on **"Select to change" page**:

[image]

Then clicking on **Yes, I'm sure** to try deleting data:

[image]

Deleting data is retried 2 times in addition to a normal try as shown below:

```
Exception occurs # Normal try
Exception occurs # 1st retry
Exception occurs # 2st retry
[31/Dec/2022 00:18:54] "POST /admin/store/person/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[31/Dec/2022 00:18:55] "GET /admin/store/person/ HTTP/1.1" 200 23013
[31/Dec/2022 00:18:55] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3195
```

And, transaction is run 3 times (The light blue one is a normal try and the yellow ones are 2 retries) according to **the PostgreSQL query logs** below:

[image]

Then finally, the page is redirected to **"Select to change" page** without deleting data but I don't know how to remove **the default message "Successfully deleted 2 persons."** as shown below:

[image]

In addition, if you want to retry 3 times with 0.5 interval seconds by default with `@retry`, you need to change `count = 2` to `count = 3` and `interval=1` to `interval=0.5` respectively as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

# ...
                 # ↓ Here
def retry(count, interval=0.5):
    def _retry(func):
        def core(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal count
            if callable(count):
                count = 3 # <= Here
            for i in range(count+1):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except DatabaseError as e:
                    print(e)
                    if i == count:            
                        messages.error(args[1], "Error occurred, try again!")                        
                        return redirect("/".join(args[1].path.split('/')[0:4]))
                    sleep(interval)
        return core
    
    if callable(count):
        return _retry(count)
    return _retry

# ...
```