# How to run a query with an inner query in it in Django?

Tags: python, django, object, django-queryset, inner-query

I'm trying to run a query with an inner query in it as shown below:

```py
                                    # Inner query
Product.objects.filter(category__in=Category.objects.get(pk=1))
```

But, I got the error below:

> TypeError: 'Category' object is not iterable

Also, I'm trying to run a query with an inner query in it as shown below:

```py
                                # Inner query
Product.objects.filter(category=Category.objects.filter(pk=1))
```

But, I got the error below:

> ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

So, how can I run these queries above with inner queries in them?

Answer (score 1):

To [category__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#in), you need to assign the queryset made by [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) instead of the object made by [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#get) as shown below:

```py
                                                    # Here
Product.objects.filter(category__in=Category.objects.filter(pk=1))
```

And, the code below is equivalent to the code above:

```py
qs = Category.objects.filter(pk=1)
Product.objects.filter(category__in=qs)
```

And, one `SELECT` query with `WHERE IN` below is run according to the PostgreSQL query logs below. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction#answer-73432601) explaining about how to log queries in PostgreSQL:

[image]

Also to `category`, you need to assign the object made by `get()` instead of the queryset made by `filter()` as shown below:

```py
                                                # Here
Product.objects.filter(category=Category.objects.get(pk=1))
```

And, the code below is equivalent to the code above:

```py
obj = Category.objects.get(pk=1)
Product.objects.filter(category=obj)
```

And, two `SELECT` queries with `WHERE` below are run according to the PostgreSQL query logs below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Eaiser is to make a simple JOIN:

```
Product.objects.filter(category_id=1)
```

For some databases it will not matter, but MySQL is notably not very good with subqueries, so the JOIN version will outperform the subquery one.